# code push release cordova gives error in Visual studio team services

Tags: cordova, azure-pipelines, code-push

The code push release step in my build definition gives the following error
I am getting an error in code push release step in my build definition.
I am executing the release step right afteer cordova build. Cordova build is successfully completed but release step fails.

```
2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)'
```

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()

```
2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]Expanded: True

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[debug]Result: True

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8101798Z ##[section]Starting: Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z ==============================================================================

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z Task : CodePush - Release (Cordova)

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z Description : Release a Cordova app update to the CodePush service

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z Version : 1.0.5

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z Author : Microsoft Corporation

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z Help : 

2017-11-10T05:42:40.8111795Z ==============================================================================

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1157912Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=undefined

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1177902Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=d:\a\1\s

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1177902Z ##[debug]Swapping to working directory: d:\a\1\s

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1177902Z ##[debug]authType=AccessKey

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1177902Z ##[debug]accessKey=8e9a1f3c6fa9b7b572d472469017d265de1c7236

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1177902Z ##[debug]appName=Syngenta_Visit_Report1

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]deploymentName=Staging

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]platform=android

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]shouldBuild=true

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]appStoreVersion=autodetect

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]rollout=100%

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]description=

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]isMandatory=false

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]isDisabled=false

2017-11-10T05:42:41.1187880Z ##[debug]Finished Building Command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli logout

2017-11-10T05:42:42.0207706Z ##[debug]Finished Building Command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli login --accessKey "8e9a1f3c6fa9b7b572d472469017d265de1c7236"

2017-11-10T05:42:42.0207706Z ##[debug]Attempting execution of command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli login --accessKey "8e9a1f3c6fa9b7b572d472469017d265de1c7236"

2017-11-10T05:42:44.1898862Z 

2017-11-10T05:42:44.1998845Z Successfully logged-in. Your session file was written to C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\.code-push.config. You can run the code-push logout command at any time to delete this file and terminate your session.

2017-11-10T05:42:44.1998845Z 

2017-11-10T05:42:44.2038856Z Installing local cordova cli...

2017-11-10T05:43:09.8899025Z npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z d:\a\1\s

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z `-- cordova@7.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z +-- configstore@2.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z | +-- dot-prop@3.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z | | `-- is-obj@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5326001Z | | `-- minimist@0.0.8 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5385996Z | | | +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5385996Z | | | +-- proxy-addr@2.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5385996Z | | | | +-- forwarded@0.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5385996Z | | | | `-- ipaddr.js@1.5.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5385996Z | | | +-- qs@6.5.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- range-parser@1.2.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- send@0.16.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | | +-- destroy@1.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | | `-- mime@1.4.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- serve-static@1.13.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- setprototypeof@1.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- statuses@1.3.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- type-is@1.6.15 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | | `-- media-typer@0.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | `-- utils-merge@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | `-- open@0.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | +-- dep-graph@1.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | `-- underscore@1.2.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | +-- glob@7.1.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | `-- fs.realpath@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | +-- init-package-json@1.10.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | +-- glob@7.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | +-- npm-package-arg@5.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | `-- hosted-git-info@2.5.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | +-- promzard@0.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | +-- read@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | `-- mute-stream@0.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | +-- read-package-json@2.0.12 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5395991Z | | | +-- glob@7.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- ansistyles@0.1.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- archy@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- async-some@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- block-stream@0.0.9 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- char-spinner@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- chmodr@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- chownr@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- cmd-shim@2.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- columnify@1.5.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- wcwidth@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- defaults@1.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- clone@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- config-chain@1.1.10 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- proto-list@1.2.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- dezalgo@1.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- asap@2.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- editor@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- fs-vacuum@1.2.9 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- fs-write-stream-atomic@1.0.8 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- iferr@0.1.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- fstream@1.0.10 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- fstream-npm@1.1.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | `-- fstream-ignore@1.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- github-url-from-git@1.4.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- github-url-from-username-repo@1.0.2

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | +-- glob@7.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5405995Z | | | +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- imurmurhash@0.1.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- inflight@1.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- inherits@2.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- ini@1.3.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- init-package-json@1.9.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | +-- glob@6.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- promzard@0.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- lockfile@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- lru-cache@4.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | +-- pseudomap@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- yallist@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- minimatch@3.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | +-- balanced-match@0.4.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- concat-map@0.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- minimist@0.0.8 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- node-gyp@3.6.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- semver@5.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- nopt@3.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- normalize-git-url@3.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- npm-cache-filename@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- npm-install-checks@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- npm-package-arg@4.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | +-- npm-registry-client@7.2.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | +-- concat-stream@1.5.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | | +-- readable-stream@2.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5415994Z | | | | | +-- isarray@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | `-- typedarray@0.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- retry@0.10.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- npm-user-validate@0.1.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- npmlog@2.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- are-we-there-yet@1.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | `-- delegates@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- gauge@1.2.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- has-unicode@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- lodash.pad@4.4.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | +-- lodash._baseslice@4.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | +-- lodash._basetostring@4.12.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | `-- lodash.tostring@4.1.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- lodash.padend@4.5.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- lodash.padstart@4.5.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- once@1.4.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- opener@1.4.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- osenv@0.1.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- os-homedir@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- os-tmpdir@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- path-is-inside@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- read@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- mute-stream@0.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- read-installed@4.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- debuglog@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- readdir-scoped-modules@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- util-extend@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | +-- read-package-json@2.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | +-- glob@6.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- json-parse-helpfulerror@1.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5425994Z | | | `-- jju@1.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | +-- readable-stream@2.1.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- buffer-shims@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- isarray@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | +-- realize-package-specifier@3.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | +-- request@2.74.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- aws-sign2@0.6.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- aws4@1.4.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- bl@1.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | `-- readable-stream@2.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | +-- isarray@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- caseless@0.11.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- combined-stream@1.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- extend@3.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- forever-agent@0.6.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- form-data@1.0.0-rc4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | `-- async@1.5.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | +-- har-validator@2.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | +-- chalk@1.1.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5436021Z | | | | | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | | `-- supports-color@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | +-- commander@2.9.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | +-- is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | | +-- generate-function@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | | +-- generate-object-property@1.2.0

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5446008Z | | | | | | `-- is-property@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | | +-- jsonpointer@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | | `-- xtend@4.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | `-- pinkie@2.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | +-- hawk@3.1.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | +-- boom@2.10.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | +-- cryptiles@2.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\a\1\s\package.json'

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5456012Z | | | | +-- hoek@2.16.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z npm WARN s No description

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | `-- sntp@1.0.9 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- http-signature@1.1.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- assert-plus@0.2.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- jsprim@1.3.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | | +-- extsprintf@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | | +-- json-schema@0.2.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | | `-- verror@1.3.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | `-- sshpk@1.9.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- asn1@0.2.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- assert-plus@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- dashdash@1.14.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- getpass@0.1.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- jodid25519@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | +-- jsbn@0.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | `-- tweetnacl@0.13.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- isstream@0.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- mime-types@2.1.11 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | | `-- mime-db@1.23.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- node-uuid@1.4.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- oauth-sign@0.8.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- qs@6.2.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- stringstream@0.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- tough-cookie@2.3.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | `-- tunnel-agent@0.4.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | +-- retry@0.10.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | +-- rimraf@2.5.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | +-- semver@5.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | +-- sha@2.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | `-- readable-stream@2.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5466017Z | | | +-- isarray@0.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- slide@1.1.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- sorted-object@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- tar@2.2.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- text-table@0.2.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- uid-number@0.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- umask@1.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- spdx-exceptions@1.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- validate-npm-package-name@2.2.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- builtins@0.0.7 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- which@1.2.11 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- isexe@1.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- wrappy@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | `-- write-file-atomic@1.1.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | +-- opener@1.4.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | +-- plist@2.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- base64-js@1.1.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | `-- xmlbuilder@8.2.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | +-- properties-parser@0.3.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | `-- string.prototype.codepointat@0.2.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | +-- request@2.79.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- aws-sign2@0.6.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- aws4@1.6.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- caseless@0.11.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- combined-stream@1.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- extend@3.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- forever-agent@0.6.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- form-data@2.1.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | `-- asynckit@0.4.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | +-- har-validator@2.0.6 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | +-- commander@2.11.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | +-- is-my-json-valid@2.16.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5476016Z | | | | +-- generate-function@2.0.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | | +-- generate-object-property@1.2.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | | | `-- is-property@1.0.2 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | | `-- jsonpointer@4.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | `-- pinkie@2.0.4 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | +-- hawk@3.1.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | +-- boom@2.10.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | +-- cryptiles@2.0.5 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | +-- hoek@2.16.3 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | | `-- sntp@1.0.9 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5486013Z | | +-- http-signature@1.1.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5506015Z +-- semver-diff@2.1.0 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5506015Z `-- string-length@1.0.1 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5506015Z 

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5506015Z npm WARN s No repository field.

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5516012Z npm WARN s No README data

2017-11-10T05:43:40.5516012Z npm WARN s No license field.

2017-11-10T05:43:40.6136014Z ##[debug]Finished Building Command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli release-cordova "Syngenta_Visit_Report1"
 "android" --deploymentName "Staging" --rollout "100%" --build

2017-11-10T05:43:40.6136014Z ##[debug]Attempting execution of command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli release-cordova "Syngenta_Visit_Report1"
 "android" --deploymentName "Staging" --rollout "100%" --build

2017-11-10T05:43:41.5175965Z Running "cordova build" command:

2017-11-10T05:43:41.5175965Z 

2017-11-10T05:43:43.1816076Z 

2017-11-10T05:43:43.1816076Z You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

2017-11-10T05:43:43.2035832Z Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

2017-11-10T05:43:43.2186045Z [Error] Unable to build project. Please ensure that this is a Cordova project and that platform "android" was added with "cordova platform add android"

2017-11-10T05:43:43.2275838Z ##[debug]Finished Building Command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli logout

2017-11-10T05:43:44.1973890Z ##[debug]task result: Failed

2017-11-10T05:43:44.1973890Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Command failed: release-cordova

2017-11-10T05:43:44.1973890Z Command failed: release-cordova

2017-11-10T05:43:44.2023858Z ##[section]Finishing: Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)
```

I am unable to resolve it.Can anyone help?

```
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9461272Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9461272Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z ##[debug]Result: True
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z ##[section]Starting: Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z Task         : CodePush - Release (Cordova)
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z Description  : Release a Cordova app update to the CodePush service
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z Version      : 1.0.5
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z Help         : 
2017-11-17T06:11:01.9471275Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2201481Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=$(Build.SourceDirectory)\$\VisitReport_Br\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2211309Z ##[debug]Swapping to working directory: $(Build.SourceDirectory)\$\VisitReport_Br\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2221312Z ##[debug]load strings from: d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\lib.json
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2231307Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2241434Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2271313Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2271313Z Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
2017-11-17T06:11:02.2321330Z ##[section]Finishing: Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)
```

Error after keeping local path under(build.sourcedirectory) section empty

```
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6795222Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6795222Z ZUMOAPPNAME@1.0.0 d:\a\3\s
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6795222Z `-- (empty)
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6795222Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6795222Z 
2017-11-17T09:13:07.6835014Z npm WARN ZUMOAPPNAME@1.0.0 No description
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8445206Z npm WARN ZUMOAPPNAME@1.0.0 No license field.
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8465194Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova"
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! node v6.10.0
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! path d:\a\3\s\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\.bin\acorn.cmd
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! code EEXIST
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z 
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! Refusing to delete d:\a\3\s\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\.bin\acorn.cmd: ..\acorn\bin\acorn symlink target is not controlled by npm d:\a\3\s\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\acorn
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! File exists: d:\a\3\s\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\.bin\acorn.cmd
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z 
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR!     d:\a\3\s\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11\npm-debug.log
2017-11-17T09:13:07.8475041Z npm ERR! code 1
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9305055Z ##[debug]load strings from: d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\lib.json
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9325060Z Unhandled: Command failed: npm install cordova
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9325060Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9325060Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9365053Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: Command failed: npm install cordova
2017-11-17T09:13:07.9415050Z ##[section]Finishing: Release update to Staging (Syngenta_Visit_Report1)
```

[Full log here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ze7xGB_3P8Aa5WByRptZnL0grm_yucX9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trouble shooting for this error: Please add two tasks before CodePush task:

1) Add npm task with this setting

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H4bWAMruzfOs90xOLxgjadAd7DihaVH4

2)After npm task, add Command Line task with below setting

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bxd54kVgW4zGRwhsH_JKz_cjc1wYZ-No

Then check if the Cordova command can execute correctly

Then if you have specified the variable Build.SourceDirectory

as $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path to your app

remove it (the variable) as you have already specified the path in GET SOURCES

You do not need to add the “Build.SourceDirectory” variable in this condition. And now, you specified the working directory to “d:\a\3\s\app path” which should not exist on the build agent, but the task didn’t report that error.

The task indicated that it cannot find the config.xml since the file exist under “d:\a\3\s” rather than “d:\a\3\s\app path”.

Thus remove the “Build.SourceDirectory” variable and run the build to check

The above steps should work for the given problem

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by **the [CodePush](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.code-push) task is executing the command `code-push release-cordova` under the default working directory `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`**.

Since your cordova app is not in the root of the build repo, the task failed to execute `code-push release-cordova` command in the default working directory.

I add an issue [Can not specity the directory to execute the command code-push release-cordova](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push-vsts-extension/issues/27), you can follow up.

For Now, you can use any of below work around to build your cordova app.

#### Work around 1: still use CodePush task by adding a variable `Build.SourceDirectory`

CodePush task also can parse the variable `Build.SourceDirectory`, so you can define this variable with the value  `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path\to\cordova\app` in VAriables Tab (below is an example).

[image]

When you build this task, it find the value for the variable `Build.SourcesDirectory` firstly (if the value is empty, then find the value in `Build.SourcesDirectory`).

#### Work around 2: Use Command Line task instead the CodePush task

Settings for the Command Line task as below:

Tool: `cd`

Arguments: `path/to/your/cordova/app & code-push login <token> & code-push release-cordova AppName OS`

Below is an example settings:

[image]

**Note:** you should use [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) which install the code-push. If you want to use Hosted agent, you should install code-push firstly by `npm install -g code-push-cli`.

---

For TFVC repo, you should use the relative path instead of `$\VisitReport_Br\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11`.

Assume the cordova app is located in the relative path `Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11` for your TFVC repo `$\VisitReport_Br` as below:

```
TFVC Root 
    |____Client Components
                |____Main
                       |____Source
                               |____vr9-11
```

- IN the Get source step, if you leave the local map path empty:

  [image]

  You should specify the variable `Build.SourceDirectory` with value `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11`.

  [image]
- IN the Get source step, if you specified local map path (as the `test` in below example):

  [image]

  You should specify the variable `Build.SourceDirectory` with value `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test\Client Components\Main\Source\vr9-11`.

  [image]

**Note:** `Build.SourceDirectory` is user defined variable, and `Build.SourcesDirectory` (different from `Build.SourceDirectory`, has `s`) is predefined variable.

Comment: Thanks. But why do we need to use private agent?

Comment: Because Hosted agent doesn't install code-push (you can check the installed software here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/hosted#software). So if you execute code-push commands in command line of the Hosted agent, it won't be recongnized.

Comment: Can you codepush your cordova app successfully now?

Comment: I cannot codepush my app.I tried the workaround 1 but it gives error:

Comment: Can you show your detail changes for the VSTS build definition? And what's the build logs?

Comment: It's caused by the path is incorrect for the variable you added, I added the detail in my answer, you can build again to check if you can build successful.

Comment: I built it keeping the 'local path under$build source directory' section empty. It gives another error npm install cordova failed.

Comment: Please check if your TFVC folder structure as I listed. If not, you should use the related relative path. If yes, please provide the build log here.

Comment: I have updated the log in the question.Path that you have mentioned is correct.

Comment: It seems it's not the log for CodePush task, which step did the build failed, Get Source step?

Comment: Actually its log for entire build definition. Go to Phase1 folder and there are log files for every step. "Release update to staging" contains logs for the step that caused build to fail

Comment: Yes, I found the codepush step in the log. And sorry for the delay since I was out of office last two days. I'll continue for the case soon after dealing with the another thing I'm taking.

Comment: What auth method did you use? What if you change the configuration of the CodePush task as below: selected **Service Endpoint (CodePush)** for Authentication Method -> Add **NEW** Service Endpoint with name and codepush token -> select the name as Service Endpoint -> build again?

Comment: Actually I used access key authentication method. I don't think auth method is an issue because in the log files it indicates "Successfully logged-in. Your session file was written to C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\.code-push.config. You can run the code-push logout command at any time to delete this file and terminate your session."

Comment: No, it's seems project related, you can refer my build log here https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApIKkY1MTjMRgm-cRONdBAprDj9M. Besides, you can also have a try to queue the build on private agent.

Comment: Thanks.Can you share the structure of your project so that I can crosscheck  with my project structure?

Comment: I resolved the previous error and cordova is getting installed but I am getting another error "cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. Unable to prepare project. Please ensure that this is a Cordova project and that platform "android" was added with "cordova platform add android"".  This is the log file for the error https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvRH3TKojcaWgYh4Ta-Knrs2Xtvxbw

Comment: In your local repo, please check if you added android platform by `cordova platform ls`. If not, you should add android platform by `cordova platform add android`. Then checkin the changes to VSTS, and build again.

Comment: In the platforms folder, there is an android folder and platforms.json also contains android entry.

Comment: Did you use Hosted agent to queue the build?

Comment: Yes I used hosted agent to build.

Comment: But I can use host agent well for the cordova cli. In order to trouble shooting for this error, please add two tasks **before** CodePush task: Add **npm task** with this setting https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApIKkY1MTjMRgnDQi7nqmOiXTaee. After npm task, add  **Command Line task** with below setting https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApIKkY1MTjMRgnG6tSqL72GcWUol. Then check if the cordova command can execute correctly.

Comment: Marina, I tried the solution and it seems to work as cordova prepare worked. But it gives another error now https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UQl0H1pBIqg6xUspgVXbrXbqyquV8GNk This the error log  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RAB3aKBPcNxl_ga2pgQDJulPUBnC5nEF

Comment: You can debug your app by removing `before_prepare` hook in `plugin.xml` file. And check if the build result is different.

Comment: I don't have before_prepare hook.

Comment: Now i guess half of my problem is solved only one error if resolved will save my week and i have tried to rephrase my question based on the current error as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411013/code-push-unable-to-release-on-vsts

Pls do get back if you know the solution to the above error

Comment: If you are not using before_prepare and after_prepare etc, please update your plugin.xml file as I said in last comment. As the example plugin.xml https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/blob/master/plugin.xml, it should remove the 5 lines which start with `<hook src=`.