# CODE-PUSH unable to release on VSTS

Tags: android, cordova, tfs, azure-devops

While trying to release via code-push on VSTS getting the following error:

Unable to find or read "config.xml" in the CWD. The "release-cordova" command must be executed in a Cordova project folder

```
2017-11-21T09:22:35.1120732Z [Error]  Unable to find or read "config.xml" in the CWD. The "release-cordova" command must be executed in a Cordova project folder.
2017-11-21T09:22:35.1200947Z ##[debug]Finished Building Command: node d:\a\_tasks\CodePushReleaseCordova_f5990527-f512-4c14-9f8e-1254240dc3cb\1.0.5\node_modules\code-push-cli\script\cli logout
2017-11-21T09:22:36.2276558Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2017-11-21T09:22:36.2295997Z Command failed: release-cordova
2017-11-21T09:22:36.2326120Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Command failed: release-cordova
```

Here's the screenshot attached of the problem:

[image]

For the detailed log: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SMk0N47A8OGm5PDUk5e86sPygmMAjD5X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trouble shooting for this error:
Please add two tasks before CodePush task:

1) Add npm task with this setting

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H4bWAMruzfOs90xOLxgjadAd7DihaVH4

2)After npm task, add Command Line task with below setting

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bxd54kVgW4zGRwhsH_JKz_cjc1wYZ-No

Then check if the Cordova command can execute correctly

Then if you have specified the variable *Build.SourceDirectory*

as *$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path to your app*

remove it (the variable) as you have already specified the path in GET SOURCES

You do not need to add the “Build.SourceDirectory” variable in this condition. And now, you specified the working directory to “d:\a\3\s\app path” which should not exist on the build agent, but the task didn’t report that error.

The task indicated that it cannot find the config.xml since the file exist under “d:\a\3\s” rather than “d:\a\3\s\app path”.

Thus remove the “Build.SourceDirectory” variable and run the build to check

The above steps should work for the given problem